# How can I inherit a style across multiple fields of an object?

Tags: css, typescript, styles

I have an object called typography with some styles and it turned out that in each case the property line-height is equal to 135%. As it happens in life, it will probably change so I would like to avoid the change in many places and create some object field or something like that to inherit it. This is piece of my current object.

```
const typography = {
  globalStyles: `
      font-family: Lato;
      font-style: normal;
      color: #000000;`,
  header: {
    XXL: `
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 37px;
        line-height: 135%;`,
    XL: `
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 33px;
        line-height: 135%;`,
    L: `
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 29px;
        line-height: 135%;`,
    M: `
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 25px;
        line-height: 135%;`,
    S: `
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 21px;
        line-height: 135%;`,
    bold: {
        ...
    },
  },
  body: {
      ...
  }
}
```

I have tried to solve this by creating property `lineHeight:line-height: 135%;` and trigger it using spread operator `...this.lineHeight` but it didn't work. Code below:

```
const typography = {
  lineHeight: `line-height: 135%;`,
  globalStyles: `
      font-family: Lato;
      font-style: normal;
      color: #000000;`,
  header: {
    XXL: `
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 37px;
        ...this.lineHeight`,
    XL: `
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 33px;
        ...this.lineHeight`,
    L: `
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 29px;
        ...this.lineHeight `,
    M: `
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 25px;
        ...this.lineHeight`,
    S: `
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 21px;
        ...this.lineHeight`,
    bold: {
        ...
    },
  },
  body: {
      ...
  }
}
```

Please about any help!

Answer (score 1):

Your styles are actually only strings and you are already using template strings. So you can just leverage that and extract the value for line-height into it's own variable outside like this:

```
const lineHeight = '135%'; // Your extracted lineHeight

const typography = {
  globalStyles: `
      font-family: Lato;
      font-style: normal;
      color: #000000;`,
  header: {
    XXL: `
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 37px;
        line-height: ${lineHeight};`, // Use the lineHeight inside your string template
    XL: `
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 33px;
        line-height: ${lineHeight};`,
    L: `
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 29px;
        line-height: ${lineHeight};`,
    M: `
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 25px;
        line-height: ${lineHeight};`,
    S: `
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 21px;
        line-height: ${lineHeight};`,
    bold: {
        ...
    },
  },
  body: {
      ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use the property `em` for this.
`em` Takes the font-size of the parent element and you can double it with `2em` as example.
So your code would look like this:

```
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 37px;
line-height: 1.35em;
```

In this case it would multiply 37 * 1.35.

I hope this is the thing you asked for.

Comment: No, it won't solve the problem, because one way or another I can change this style in many places. What's more my font-size could change in time either, and it generate next problem...